# adding new values to session variables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

> I am storing  username and name in session

```
foreach($data as  $key=>$val)
                        {   
                            if($val->username == $username && $val->password == md5($password) )
                            {
                                $flag=true;
                                $newdata =array('name'=>$val->name,'username'=>$username);
                                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
                                break;
                            }
```

> Now, a user uploads his profile picture, its path gets stored in database, and after that , i am getting that image from database.

```
public function get_image(){

            $this->load->model('UploadModel');
            $path= $this->UploadModel->get_path();

        }
```

> If i echo $path i got 
>   [{"img_path":"http://205.147.101.117/secureadmin/managment-panel/uploads/download_(1)2.jpg"}]

Now I want to store this path in my session variable , so that everytime i login the profile picture got displayed. 
Now i have 2 questions :
1) How to store this image path in already created session varible 
2) Is there anyother way, to display profile picture..

Thank you, in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to put session name into session function as like below

```
$this->session->set_userdata('new_user_session_name', $newdata);
```

Comment: I am getting my image path as [{"img_path":"http:\/\/205.147.101.117\/secureadmin\/managment-panel\/uploads\/download_(1)2.jpg"}] and want to set this path in my session $newdata , so that every time my session run , user profile image got displayed.

Comment: Can you share more script that we can understand why it is happening

Answer (score 0):

You can set new session variable when the user successfully upload profile image.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('session_variable_name', 'variable_data');
```

Or the plain old `$_SESSION['profile_image'] = 'iamge_uploaded';`

You don't always have to create an array of the session variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a new session variable like this :

```
$this->session->set_userdata('session_name', $newdata);
```

The $newdata will be now in your session object